# could not copy 'formula' from input line in libreoffice?

Tags: libreoffice

Why I can not copy formula from the input line in libreoffice so that I can use that in different file? I can select it but not copy it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> can do the job.
this short cut is supported by the clipboard manager in `gnome-settings-daemon`.

Answer (score 1):

LO doesn't provide a context menu in the formula input line, but all the actions from the "Edit" menu are available - among them "Copy", "Cut" and "Paste" with their corresponding shortcuts.